# Countryinfo package giving Keyerror

Tags: python, error-handling

My code:

```
country = CountryInfo('Singapore')
p = country.population()
print(p)
```

First line is giving an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 7, in <module>
    p = country.population()
  File "/home/runner/testing/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/countryinfo/countryinfo.py", line 240, in population
    _population = self.__countries[self.__country_name]['population']
KeyError: 'singapore'
```

I've installed the package using `pip install countryinfo`. Changing it to uppercase, lowercase or capitalizing the first letter doesn't work. How should I fix this?

Comment: Not reproducible after installing the package on Python 3.10

Comment: I had a look at that module's source code, and the way it loads data from json files is terrifying. Most likely you're missing the `data` directory containing all the json files, for whatever reason. It should be located at `site-packages/countryinfo/data`.